# npm install from C# code fails

Tags: c#, process, bundle, npm-install

I am trying to perform `npm install` from C# code using process. The bundle directory is product of meteor build, and npm install inside \bundle\programs\server is mandatory operation before running the build.

Here is C# code:

```
processInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
processInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
processInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
processInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
processInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
processInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\some_service\bundle\programs\server";
processInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node.exe";
processInfo.Arguments = "npm install";
process = Process.Start(processInfo);
process.WaitForExit();

stderr_str = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
stdout_str = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```

And the error code in **stderr_str**  variable is:

```
    module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\some_service\bundle\programs\server\npm'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:935:3
```

It works fine when I run this manually via cms in corresponding directory. Why it would be problem from C#, or am I doing this right?

Any suggestion or hint would be helpful.

EDIT1:

After running with change from answer I got error:

Change :

```
    processInfo.FileName =  @"C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node.exe";
    processInfo.Arguments = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js install";
```

Erorr:

```
module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Program'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:935:3
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`npm` is actually a `.cmd` file next to `node.exe`.

So you should be able to just run that directly from the folder without `node.exe`.

```
processInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\npm.cmd";
processInfo.Arguments = "install";
```

Or if you want `node.exe` for some reason, you should be able to do this:

```
processInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node.exe";
processInfo.Arguments = "\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js\" install";
```

Comment: The first suggestion with npm.cmd runs forever.

Comment: Please try the same way I posted in the answer. I added enclosing quotes around the path to npm-cli.js. Because Program Files has a whitespace in it, quotes around the path are required. That's why in the error message it tells you that it can't find `'C:\Program'`. It cuts off the rest.

Comment: I did try it exactly and it runs forever also. This answer makes perfect sense. I just do not see why it taking so long. It seem to be wrong.

Comment: Runs perfectly on my end. How long it takes to run "npm install" from cmd?

Comment: 30 seconds not more.

Comment: For some reason it works only if I set processInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false; Thank you.